# Kickstart file is ignored by the installer

Tags: 10.10, installation, ubiquity, kickstart

I have fallowed [this guide](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/unattended-ubuntu-installations/2/) to create a kickstart file to install ubuntu automatically.
However the problem is that when I boot the menu item

```
label autoinstall
  menu label ^Auto install
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/ks.cfg --
```

it doesn't start the installer. I've tried using automatic-ubiquity as one of the parameters, but still it seems that kickstart file isn't used.

Is there a way to make this work, or is there another way (preferably **without** using network, like FAI).

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/automated-remote-installs-of-ubuntu-using-kickstart-802660/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the alternative cd not the live cd:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

If you follow exactly the tutorial you mentioned it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz \
ks=/cdrom/ks.cfg

You have repeatedly using "**file=**" twice.
To appoint where your target KickStart template file is, use "**ks=**" instead of "**file=**"